# The systemtray( right top system bar) coming with a blank button, how to fix it?

Tags: unity

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04LTS and already update to date.The right top system bar coming with a blank button, click that button will show a blank menu(I mean a menu with no content, but only contains border.). Is anyone can tell me how to fix this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That looks like it is an application indicator. You have some process running which is adding the indicator. Find and terminate the process which is providing a blank indicator, and it will go away.

Comment: I tried to find such a process that produce a redundant indicator, but not take effect. Here is what I do:  kill all other gui software, using the default ubuntu theme and icons. I remember this phenomenon happended when last week I installed all the updates from ubuntu source and reboot. Anyway, it does not block me from using my computer.

Comment: App indicators don't necessarily come from "GUI" applications which exist in the applications menu. Like dropbox for example.